# Updating 'Available Version' in .so

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, shared-library, elf

I'm trying to run the gitbook-editor on Arch Linux, and running in the openssl version issues. The error messages states:

```
.... /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found ...
```

However this library is defining following versions:

```
1 0x01 0x09bbb660 libssl.so.1.0.0
2 0x00 0x06a2b2e4 OPENSSL_1.0.2d
3 0x00 0x06a2b2e7 OPENSSL_1.0.2g
        OPENSSL_1.0.2d
```

Question: 
Is there any utility using which i can just add the version 'OPENSSL_1.0.0' to 
my copy of libssl.so.1.0.0 ?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get your `libssl.so.1.0.0`? The file you have shouldn’t be called 1.0.0 since it’s 1.0.2 and that has a different soname.

Comment: This is archlinux  ; https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/log/trunk?h=packages/openssl-1.0